# Multiple images uploading issue

Tags: javascript, php, image-uploading, filereader

I am trying to insert multiple images in database. On submit, i am getting only one image details in $_FILES[].
Why the other submitted images are not displaying in array?

Also, upload.php has error saying 
Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\kabootar\upload.php on line 15 that is

```
$targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName;
```

How can i solve these problems?

html

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="upload">

        <label class="add">Select more..</label>
         <div class="prep">

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img" />
   <input type="file" class="inputimg" name="multiple_uploaded_files[]" />
        </div>


         </div>

    </form>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".img", function () {

    $(this).closest("div").find(".inputimg").trigger("click");
});

var count = 1;
$(".add").on("click", function () {
    count++;
    if(count <= 5){
        var row = '<div class="col-md-4"> <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img"/ ><input type="file" class="inputimg" />\n\
       ';
    $(".prep").append(row);

    $(".inputimg").change(function () {
        console.log(this);
        readURL(this);
    });
    }else{
        alert('You are only allowed to add uptp 5 images');
    }


});
$(".inputimg").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(input).siblings('.img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

upload.php

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{

if(!empty($_FILES)){

  foreach ($_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'] as $file)
 {
    $targetDir = "upload/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'];   
    $targetFile = $targetDir.$fileName; 
        //use the move_uploaded_file() to move your file on your server directory.
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$file], $targetFile))
{
        //insert file information into db table
 $sql = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$fileName."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
 echo 'file inserted';  
 }
    else
    {
        echo 'Query not working';
    }

}
        //fire an insert query that inserts all the file names with comma separated value
    }
else
{
    echo 'No file selected';
}
```

Comment: can you print/show the var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: @RavinderReddy
After sending two files the output is

array(1) { ["multiple_uploaded_files"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "Winter.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE0.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(105542) } } }

Comment: `$_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name']` is an array!

Comment: @Rayon
Yup it's an array and declared in form

Comment: @bc110402307SyedZeeshanHaide, You can not concatenate `array` with `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to concat string with array $_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'].  For Array to string conversion error

replace the code

```
$fileName = $_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'];
```

with

```
$fileName = $file;   (or)
$fileName = $_FILES['multiple_uploaded_files']['name'][0];
```

Single file upload issue. You have not added name attribute for the input tag in javascript code.

replace

```
    var row = '<div class="col-md-4"> <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img"/ ><input type="file" class="inputimg" />\n\';
```

With

```
    var row = '<div class="col-md-4"> <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/129/soft_scraps/256/button_upload_01.png" id="upfile1" style="cursor:pointer" class="img"/ ><input type="file" class="inputimg" name="multiple_uploaded_files[]"/>\n\';
```

Note: added name attribute to the input tag.

Comment: you need to change the php code accordingly. print/show the var_dump($_FILES); after javascript change.

Comment: No need of one more query. You have to make correct loop. can you print/show it var_dump($_FILES);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114552/discussion-between-ravinder-reddy-and-bc110402307-syed-zeeshan-haide).